# Valid JavaScript API Domain for linkedIn to use in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth, linkedin-api

What should be a better way to specify a valid SDK domain for LinkedIn Oauth while using it in your Chrome extension?

I am trying implement LinkedIn Oauth in my chrome extension and got confused because chrome extension it completely different environment than a simple web application. Don't what should be callbacks functions.

If anyone has done linked Oauth with Chrome extension then please share your experience.

Comment: I did it for facebook. Create a script in a server you control and let it handle the authentication and pass the token to the extension

Comment: @cornwell will you please share code or link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) to handle OAuth, then you can specify

```
https://<extension-id>.chromiumapp.org/<anything-here>
```

as your callback URL. Note that no network request will actually go to that address - it'll be automatically intercepted in your extension. See the [Non-Google account authentication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity#non) guide in the docs.

---

Note that this potentially involves putting your secret API keys inside the extension. If you want to avoid that, you'll need to set up your own server to handle it for you (and not use `chrome.identity`).